# c++ multithreaded tcp server using futures and async

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets, winsock2

I recently started studying c++ and I'm following some tutorials. I was looking into sockets and I decided as a side project to create a small multithreaded server as you can see below.

I was trying to close the servers listening socket once `CLIENTS_MAX_NUM` reached and then reopen it once a socket disconnects, however this is giving me an error 10022 (WSAEINVAL) and I'm not quite sure what I'm doing wrong.

In case you want to reproduce the error just connect using telnet and close the client connection (ctrl+] , quit).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <future>
#include <chrono>
#include <WS2tcpip.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")

static constexpr const unsigned int PORT = 5000;
static constexpr const unsigned int CLIENTS_MAX_NUM = 1;
static constexpr const unsigned int CLIENTS_QUEUE_NUM = 10;
SOCKET server_sock;
std::vector<std::future<void>> futures;
std::mutex mtx;

void initialize_winsock() {

    WSAData wsData;
    WORD ver = MAKEWORD(2, 2);

    int wsResult = WSAStartup(ver, &wsData);

    if (wsResult != 0) {

        std::cerr << WSAGetLastError() << std::endl;

        WSACleanup();
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    }

}

void bind_server_socket() {
    
    int keep_alive = 1;
    int re_use = 1;

    if (setsockopt(server_sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_KEEPALIVE, (const char*)&keep_alive, sizeof(keep_alive)) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        
        closesocket(server_sock);
        WSACleanup();
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    }

    if (setsockopt(server_sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (const char*)&re_use, sizeof(re_use)) == SOCKET_ERROR) {

        closesocket(server_sock);
        WSACleanup();
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    }

    sockaddr_in server;

    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_port = htons(PORT);
    server.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = INADDR_ANY;

    memset(&server.sin_zero, 0, 8);

    if (bind(server_sock, (sockaddr*)&server, sizeof(sockaddr)) == SOCKET_ERROR) {

        std::cerr << WSAGetLastError() << std::endl;

        closesocket(server_sock);
        WSACleanup();
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    }



}

void open_server_socket(bool &listening) {
    
    server_sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

    if (server_sock == INVALID_SOCKET) {

        std::cerr << WSAGetLastError() << std::endl;

        listening = false;

        WSACleanup();
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    }

    listening = true;

}

void close_server_socket(bool &listening) {
    
    closesocket(server_sock);

    listening = false;

}

void handle_client(SOCKET client_sock, sockaddr_in client) {
    
    char buf[4096];
    char host[NI_MAXHOST];
    char service[NI_MAXHOST];

    memset(host, 0, NI_MAXHOST);
    memset(service, 0, NI_MAXHOST);

    //std::cout << std::this_thread::get_id() << std::endl;

    if (getnameinfo((sockaddr*)&client, sizeof(client), host, NI_MAXHOST, service, NI_MAXSERV, 0) == 0) {

        std::cout << host << " connected on port " << service << std::endl;

    }
    else {

        inet_ntop(AF_INET, &client.sin_addr, host, NI_MAXHOST);

        std::cout << host << " connected on port " << ntohs(client.sin_port) << std::endl;

    }

    while (true) {

        memset(&buf, 0, 4096);

        const int bytes_received = recv(client_sock, buf, 4096, 0);

        if (bytes_received == SOCKET_ERROR) {

            std::cerr << WSAGetLastError() << std::endl;

            WSACleanup();

        }
        else if (bytes_received == 0) {

            std::cout << "client disconnected" << std::endl;
            break;

        }
        else {

            send(client_sock, buf, bytes_received + 1, 0);

        }

    }

}

int main(int argc, const char* argv[]) {
    
    bool listening = false;

    initialize_winsock();
    open_server_socket(listening);
    bind_server_socket();

    // -----------------------------------------------------------

    if (listen(server_sock, CLIENTS_QUEUE_NUM) == SOCKET_ERROR) {

        std::cerr << WSAGetLastError() << std::endl;

        closesocket(server_sock);
        WSACleanup();
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    }
    else {

        std::cout << "listening for incoming connections on port " << PORT << std::endl;

        while (true) {

            unsigned int removed = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < futures.size(); i++) {

                auto status = futures.at(i).wait_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(0));

                if (status == std::future_status::ready) {

                    futures.erase(futures.begin() + i);

                    removed++;

                }

            }

            if (removed > 1) {
                std::cout << removed << " clients removed" << std::endl;
            }
            else if (removed) {
                std::cout << removed << " client removed" << std::endl;
            }

            if (futures.size() < CLIENTS_MAX_NUM && !listening) {

                std::cout << "re-opening server socket" << std::endl;

                open_server_socket(listening);

                // BOOM <--- 10022 (WSAEINVAL) - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/windows-sockets-error-codes-2

            }

            if (listening) {

                sockaddr_in client;

                memset(&client.sin_zero, 0, 8);

                int client_size = sizeof(client);

                SOCKET client_sock = accept(server_sock, (sockaddr*)&client, &client_size);

                if (client_sock == INVALID_SOCKET) {

                    std::cerr << WSAGetLastError() << std::endl;

                    closesocket(server_sock);
                    WSACleanup();
                    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

                }
                else {
                    
                    futures.emplace_back(std::async(std::launch::async, &handle_client, client_sock, client));

                    if (futures.size() >= CLIENTS_MAX_NUM && listening) {

                        std::cout << "closing server socket" << std::endl;

                        close_server_socket(listening);

                    }

                    std::cout << futures.size() << " clients connected" << std::endl;

                }

            }

        }

    }

    // ----------------------------------------------------------

    std::cout << "bye!" << std::endl;

    WSACleanup();
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);

}
```

Comment: What specifically gives you that error? The close? The reopen? Or perhaps the next time you call accept with a server socket you reopened but did not re-bind?

Comment: when I try re-opening the socket line-number 211 (where the comment is). I tried calling `bind_server_socket` also after re-opening but the same error occurs. So I'm guessing it's something else?

Answer (score 0):

After some digging I found a couple silly errors, below is the working code:

**update**

Also fixed the vector loop

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <future>
#include <chrono>
#include <WS2tcpip.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")

static constexpr const unsigned int PORT = 5000;
static constexpr const unsigned int CLIENTS_MAX_NUM = 5;
static constexpr const unsigned int CLIENTS_QUEUE_NUM = 0;

void handle_client(SOCKET client_sock, sockaddr_in client) {

    char buf[4096];
    char host[NI_MAXHOST];
    char service[NI_MAXHOST];

    memset(host, 0, NI_MAXHOST);
    memset(service, 0, NI_MAXHOST);

    //std::cout << std::this_thread::get_id() << std::endl;

    if (getnameinfo((sockaddr*)&client, sizeof(client), host, NI_MAXHOST, service, NI_MAXSERV, 0) == 0) {

        std::cout << host << " connected on port " << service << std::endl;

    }
    else {

        inet_ntop(AF_INET, &client.sin_addr, host, NI_MAXHOST);

        std::cout << host << " connected on port " << ntohs(client.sin_port) << std::endl;

    }

    while (true) {

        memset(&buf, 0, 4096);

        const int bytes_received = recv(client_sock, buf, 4096, 0);

        if (bytes_received == SOCKET_ERROR) {

            std::cerr << WSAGetLastError() << std::endl;

            WSACleanup();

        }
        else if (bytes_received == 0) {

            std::cout << "client disconnected" << std::endl;
            break;

        }
        else {

            send(client_sock, buf, bytes_received + 1, 0);

        }

    }

}

void initialize_winsock() {

    WSAData wsData;
    WORD ver = MAKEWORD(2, 2);

    int wsResult = WSAStartup(ver, &wsData);

    if (wsResult != 0) {

        std::cerr << WSAGetLastError() << std::endl;

        WSACleanup();
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    }

}

void bind_server_socket(SOCKET &server_sock) {
    
    int keep_alive = 1;
    int re_use = 1;

    if (setsockopt(server_sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_KEEPALIVE, (const char*)&keep_alive, sizeof(keep_alive)) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        
        closesocket(server_sock);
        WSACleanup();
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    }

    if (setsockopt(server_sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (const char*)&re_use, sizeof(re_use)) == SOCKET_ERROR) {

        closesocket(server_sock);
        WSACleanup();
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    }

    sockaddr_in server;

    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_port = htons(PORT);
    server.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = INADDR_ANY;

    memset(&server.sin_zero, 0, 8);

    if (bind(server_sock, (sockaddr*)&server, sizeof(sockaddr)) == SOCKET_ERROR) {

        std::cerr << WSAGetLastError() << std::endl;

        closesocket(server_sock);
        WSACleanup();
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    }



}

void open_server_socket(SOCKET &server_sock, bool &accepting) {
    
    server_sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

    if (server_sock == INVALID_SOCKET) {

        std::cerr << WSAGetLastError() << std::endl;

        accepting = false;

        WSACleanup();
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    }

    accepting = true;

}

void close_server_socket(SOCKET &server_sock, bool &accepting) {
    
    closesocket(server_sock);

    accepting = false;

}

void clear_futures(std::vector<std::future<void>> &futures) {

    std::vector<std::future<void>>::iterator it = futures.begin();

    while (it != futures.end()) {

        auto status = (*it).wait_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(0));

        if (status == std::future_status::ready) {

            it = futures.erase(it);

        }
        else {
            ++it;
        }
    }

}

void wait_for_connections(std::vector<std::future<void>> &futures, SOCKET &server_sock, bool& accepting) {

    if (listen(server_sock, CLIENTS_QUEUE_NUM) == SOCKET_ERROR) {

        std::cerr << WSAGetLastError() << std::endl;

        closesocket(server_sock);
        WSACleanup();
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    }
    else {

        std::cout << "accepting for incoming connections on port " << PORT << std::endl;

        while (true) {

            if (futures.size() < CLIENTS_MAX_NUM && !accepting) {

                std::cout << "re-opening server socket" << std::endl;

                open_server_socket(server_sock, accepting);
                bind_server_socket(server_sock);
                wait_for_connections(futures, server_sock, accepting);

                break;

            }

            if (accepting) {

                sockaddr_in client;

                memset(&client.sin_zero, 0, 8);

                int client_size = sizeof(client);

                SOCKET client_sock = accept(server_sock, (sockaddr*)&client, &client_size);

                if (client_sock == INVALID_SOCKET) {

                    std::cerr << WSAGetLastError() << std::endl;

                    closesocket(server_sock);
                    WSACleanup();
                    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

                }

                clear_futures(futures);

                futures.emplace_back(std::async(std::launch::async, &handle_client, client_sock, client));

                if (futures.size() >= CLIENTS_MAX_NUM && accepting) {

                    std::cout << "closing server socket" << std::endl;

                    close_server_socket(server_sock, accepting);

                }

                std::cout << futures.size() << " clients connected" << std::endl;

            }

        }

    }

}

int main(int argc, const char* argv[]) {
    
    std::vector<std::future<void>> futures;
    bool accepting = false;
    SOCKET server_sock;

    initialize_winsock();
    open_server_socket(server_sock, accepting);
    bind_server_socket(server_sock);
    wait_for_connections(futures, server_sock, accepting);

    std::cout << "bye!" << std::endl;

    WSACleanup();
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);

}
```